# How to display final date or beginning date to text or field object without using parameter field in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Passing beginning date and final date as parameter through the following code
as no parameter field is using in report,
how to display the date range in text or field object?
what is the formula to do this?

```
ReportDocument objRpt = new ReportDocument();
            string reportPath = Server.MapPath("Daily_CrystalReport.rpt");
            objRpt.Load(reportPath); 

            objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);


            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
            CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to pass the start and date end via parameters then you will have to return the values to the report via the dataset.

**EDIT:**

You will need to add the parameters to the Crystal Report via the Design View.

Give them appropriate names e.g. `@StartDate` & `@EndDate`

Then in your code

```
objRpt.ParameterFields["@StartDate"].CurrentValues.Clear();
objRpt.ParameterFields["@StartDate"].DefaultValues.Clear();
objRpt.ParameterFields["@StartDate"].CurrentValue.Add([YOUR START DATE HERE]);

objRpt.ParameterFields["@EndDate"].CurrentValues.Clear();
objRpt.ParameterFields["@EndDate"].DefaultValues.Clear();
objRpt.ParameterFields["@EndDate"].CurrentValue.Add([YOUR END DATE HERE]);
```

**EDIT 2:**

You can also add values dynamically to the Crystal Report.  Add two textboxes on to your Crystal Report and assign them names.

Then in your code you can do something like this:

```
((CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportsObjects.Item["NameOfTextObject"]).Text = YOUR DATE;
```

Comment: i mean display start and end date in report but do not know how to get the parameters in report

Comment: it can correctly show data in a period of time, but can not display end date in text object or text field in heading

Comment: but i do not need to add parameters in crystal report design view as customersTableAdapter1.FillBy(ds.CarPark, Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["start"]), Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["end"])); already done

Comment: This is the main problem that how to display enddate in crytsal report without parameter fields in crystal report design view

Comment: I am trying and reply you later

Comment: ReportObjects do not have items

Comment: Success, Thanks, Grant you a tick